# Finding Middle index in an array if sum of both ends are equal?

Tags: java

I have done half of the coding and I am not sure what should be the next step:-

```
public class Middlexindex {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     int sum=0;
    int[] myArray={1,2,3,3,2,1};
    for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
    {
        sum=sum+myArray[i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    System.out.println(sum/2);
```

Can anyone please tell me what I should do next to find the middle indexing in an array if sum of both ends are equal ?

Comment: What is your expected answer in this case? Am I right to say Middle index is simply the index of the middle term in the array?

Comment: What do you mean by "middle index"? The index of the element right in the middle of the array (what if the number is even)? Or the index to a median element (of which there could be many)?

Comment: There are 6 integers. There is no middle for that. You can divide the array's length by 2 to find the middle index. `array.length/2` is your middle index

Comment: Answer is 3 which is at the middle index 2. shree.pat18

Comment: @shortcut Yes. The indexes available: `0 1 2 3 4 5`. What did you expect?

Comment: @shortcut So you want the _value_ of the element in the array at the middle position?  That seems to be what you want when you said "Answer is 3" above.

Comment: @Vince Emigh I am sorry, I forgot to put the complete question. I have edited the question and have put the complete question now. Here middle indexing is at 2 for the value 3 from the left side for my question above.

Comment: @shortcut You want to also see if the first half of the array added together is == to the 2nd half added together? Use 2 loops, or when your index (int i) hits half way, start adding onto a new var (int sum2), then after the array, check if they are equal. EDIT: check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean the index in the middle of the length of the `myArray` array, that would be

```
int middleIndex = (myArray == null || myArray.length == 0) ? 
    -1 : myArray.length / 2; // or similar
```

Comment: if array is equal to null, it returns 0, which is not correct. It must return something like (-1)

Comment: if the array is empty, it return 0, which is out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 variables to store numbers.

```
int sum1 = 0;
int sum2 = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(i <= array.length/2)
        sum1 += sum1 + array[i];
    else
        sum2 += sum2 + array[i];
}

if(sum1 == sum2) 
    System.out.println("They are equal");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int first = 0;
    int k;
    for ( k = 0; k <= i; k++)
        first += array[k];

    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)
        sum += array[j];
    if (first == sum)
        System.out.println("your index is at ," + k );
}
```